# sql loader loading less fields than columns

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

For example, my input file looks like this

```
1;2;AAA;
```

and my database like this:

```
PK NUMBER,
C1 NUMBER,
C2 NUMBER,
C3 VARCHAR2
```

On my PK I have a sequence but I cannot use it in the .ctl file.

I am trying to use a ctl file like this: (separated by ";")

PK FILLER "function()",
C1,
C2,
C3

Yet this fails, it jumps over the first value in the input file...so

Comment: have u tried sequence function: SEQUENCE(MAX,1)

Comment: @radshk RADU - Can you post your complete SQL*Loader control file?

Comment: @Justin                                                            `LOAD DATA
  INFILE 'AlimentationFichier.data'
  BADFILE 'AlimentationFichierRejets.data'
  REPLACE
  INTO TABLE P4PCA2_PIVOT_CA
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY "||"

  (
 NUM_IDGEN_ALL_EVT   FILLER          "fff()",
  CA_DAT_EVT                      "to_date(:CA_DAT_EVT,'YYYY-MM-DD')",          
  CA_NUM_PSG_EVT                             ,
and on..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add `TRAILING NULLCOLS` to the loader and place the PK at the END so it considers it null and uses the sequence, and therefore not mix the fields order.